# Is Kerberos enabled by default for Windows Server 2016 AD domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory

> Is Kerberos enabled by default for Windows Server 2016 AD domain?

I'm new to Windows AD, so I've set up a virtual environment consisting of a Windows 2016 server and a few Windows 10 machines.

I wonder if the Windows AD use NTLM or Kerberos for network authentication (default settings)?

How can I check this? - and can both authentication mechanisms be used simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, the Kerberos protocol is used for network authentication by default for windows server 2016. But the NTLM is still supported. 
I would suggest you to see the following article to learn for more information.
For your reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/microsoft-ntlm
Please refer to images to check which protocol is used by windows AD.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phlQB.jpg)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0L9j.jpg)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBGoe.jpg)
The Location is :server manager-tools-event viewer-windows logs-security.
Search for the event log which event ID is 4624 and you can see the detailed anthentication information.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624
Also, we could use group policy to audit NTLM authentication logon attempts.
Here is the location: computer configuration- policies-windows settings-security settings-local policies-security options-network security: restrict NTLM: Audit NTLM authentication in this domain.
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7mB5.jpg)
[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoSBq.jpg)
This policy will log events for NTLM pass-through authentication requests from its servers and for its accounts so that you can check it if the NTLM is used.
Best Regards,
Roger